# LUIS Pre Built Entity are not recognized in the utterance

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have included two pre-built entities in my app, a DateTimeV2 and one Number.
[image: Pre-Built Entities]

I tried creating an intent "QueryByDate" and added this utterance:
Book Me 2 tickets on 12/21/2017. I was expecting 2 and 12/21/2017 should be identified as the prebuilt entities, but they are not.
[image: Utterance with no recognition for Pre-built entities.]

Please help me in understanding what am I missing here.

Thanks,
Subrat

Comment: Having multiple utterances will make LUIS much better are correctly recognizing your intents/utterances/entities.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit buggy. All these services are in beta so expectations should not be so high :). Go ahead and add two or three utterances. Then go and train the app. When you go back to the intent, the entities should be recognized.

[image]

I've interacted with LUIS for many hours and I must say, if you want to do natural language processing use Facebook's WIT.ai. It's an excellent platform!

Comment: Thank you Govind. That exactly solves my problem. :)  Coming to Facebook WIT.ai, can it be integrable with Microsoft BOT framework? Or is there any other framework that works best with WIT?

Comment: You can use it with any framework since WIT.ai exposes an HTTP API, but they have built [frameworks](https://wit.ai/docs) for Node.js, Ruby and Python. I recently built an AI powered Twilio messenger using WIT.ai, [Counted.IO](https://github.com/govindrai/CountedIO)